# Having Difficulty passing variables through includes using globals

Tags: php, include, global

I have a three tier tree for displaying content on a page. It uses includes to display specific PHP pages based on the URL. What doesn't happen is the variables are not understood in included PHP files.

**index.php**

```
// example url http://fakesite.com/?color=red&user=999
$user = $_GET['user'];

if ($_GET['color'] == 'red')        
       {$color = 'red';}
elseif ($_GET['color'] == 'white')      
       {$color = 'white';}
else 
       {$color = 'blue';}

global $color;
global $user;
include 'page2.php';
```

**page2.php**

```
global $color;
global $user;
echo 'hi '.$user.'I hear you like '.$color;
```

Comment: I notice you've used `include_once()`. Did you happen to include `page2.php` somewhere else earlier in the code?

Comment: @Michael No and I changed it to prevent more confusion.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need at all for those `$global` lines. Any variables defined in the main script are defined in the `include`d file. It's basically like taking the code in the `include`d file and shoving it in the place of the `include` call (with a few exceptions)

Comment: well still nothing passes through.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
include_once 'page2.php;
```

should change to:

```
include_once 'page2.php';
```

You have a missing quote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing ALL those four global lines? I don't know if that's the problem, but they're not necessary at all!

When including or requiring a file all the variables declared above are available to the included/required file.

If that didn't solve it, maybe you have the wrong path on include.

Comment: the include works. page2 just doesn't recognize the variables in the index.

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $user = $_GET['user'];

    if ($_GET['color'] == 'red')        
           {$color = 'red';}
    elseif ($_GET['color'] == 'white')      
           {$color = 'white';}
    else 
           {$color = 'blue';}
    include 'page2.php';
?>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
    echo 'hi '.$user.'I hear you like '.$color;
?>
```

**global example**

```
function dosomethingfunky(){
    global $user, $color;
    echo 'hi '.$user.'I hear you like '.$color;
}
```